# How can I sum values based on a date range and group by the MAX date?

Tags: sql, date, sum

I've got a data set like the following - Quantities and Sales $ aggregated by week and product

```
Week    Product     Quantity    Sales
----    -------     --------    -----
1       12a         6           600
2       12a         4           400
3       12a         3           300
4       12a         1           100
5       12a         3           300 
6       12a         1           100
7       12a         4           400 
8       12a         6           600
9       12a         2           200
```

For every week, I need to sum quantity and sales for that week plus the previous 3 weeks

Desired result would be:

```
Week    Product     Quantity    Sales
----    -------     --------    -----
1       12a         14          1400  --> Week 1 + Week 2 + Week 3 + Week 4 but row labeled Week 1
2       12a         11          1100
```

I feel like I need a loop to evaluate each week

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(quantity) over (partition by product
                        order by week
                        rows between current row and 3 following
                       ) as quantity,
       sum(sales) over (partition by product
                        order by week
                        rows between current row and 3 following
                       ) as sales
from t;
```